# Is $C^{\infty}$ dense in $W^{k,p}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The $C_c^{\infty}$ are certainly not sense in an arbitrary $W^{k,p}$ space. Despite, I started wondering whether at least $C^{\infty}$ is dense? Now, this can certainly not be true for general domains. Thus, the reasonable question is:

Is $C^{\infty} \cap W^{k,p} $ dense in $W^{k,p}$ on general domains $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Not for $p=\infty$. Yes for $p<\infty$. What definition of $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ are you using? One possible definition of Sobolev spaces with   $p<\infty$ is "the completion of smooth functions with respect to the Sobolev norm".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the Lawrence Evans' book about PDEs. More precisely, you can check its fifth chapter.

There, you will see that, under some really general assumptions on the open set $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $, you have that $ C^{\infty} $ is dense on $ W^{k,p} $.

About the other question, you generally have that $ C^{\infty}_c $ is **not** dense on the sobolev space. For this, see the Trace concept on Evans' book.

(Here, I am assuming that $ W^{k,p} = \{ f \in L^p \; ; \exists \partial^{\alpha} f (\text{weak sense}) \forall |\alpha| \le k, \partial^{\alpha} f \in L^p \} $ )